# RestSharp connects to WebApi - Datetime Timezone problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, restsharp

I'm having problems with Datetime properties in objects between the communication of:

- **site#1** using RestSharp
- and **site#2** using WebApi.

**Version 1**

Site#1

```
// SEND 
var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
var request = new RestRequest(serviceUrl, Method.POST);
var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
request.AddParameter("text/json", jsonBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var result = client.Execute<T>(request);

// RECEIVE 
var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
var request = new RestRequest(serviceUrl, Method.GET);
var data = client.Execute<T>(request).Data
```

Site#2

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
     new JsonSerializerSettings
         {
              DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
              DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
         };
```

RESULT:

- On site#1 I am sending 01.01.2018 12:00 AM
- On site#2 I am Receiving 01.01.2018 12:00 AM
- When site#1 requests the object, then now I am receiving: 31.12.2017 11:00 PM

**Version 2**
I have tried to use a different sending on site#1

```
request.AddJsonBody(model);
```

RESULT:

- On site#1 I am sending 01.01.2018 12:00 AM
- On site#2 I am Receiving 31.12.2017 11:00 PM
- BUT if I correct the value on the database of site#2, then the value is sent back correctly from site#2 to site#1 (basically, the opposite of version #1)

I am even making this tests in the same machine, same culture, same timezone, but of course that I would like to find a solution that would work in machines with different timezone.

Comment: You need to share the code which saves the data to database on site2. Also tell us how exactly you are populating the `model` on site1?

Comment: Do you have same serializer settings both on site1 and site2 (timezone handling). Also, could you check what are the real values of dates after serialization on site1?

Answer (score 0):

Using the version 1: I was able to fix this issue on the site#1

On the Receive part:

```
 /************************************************/
 // TRY #1 - OLD
 //var tempData = client.Execute<T>(request).Data;
 /************************************************/
 // TRY #2 - NEW
 var response = client.Execute(request);
 var tempData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
 /************************************************/
```

Now, I send/save/get the same datetime.